# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null - when reading SharePoint list with JS

Tags: sharepoint-list, google-chart

I am using an ajax call to get elements of multiple sharepoint list choice(checkboxes) columns called "Orbit", "SD",.... to create google pie charts for each column:

```
data.d.results.forEach(function(row) {
    // each row
    row.Orbit.results.forEach(function(choiceOrbit) {
        // each choice of Orbit of single row
        if (countOrbit.hasOwnProperty(choiceOrbit)) {
            countOrbit[choiceOrbit] += 1;
        } else {
            countOrbit[choiceOrbit] = 1;
        }
    });
```

But if one row in the column is empty, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null
at Statistics.aspx:658
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (Statistics.aspx:632)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

How can i add an if(), so that an empty item will be neglected in the counting? Something like:

```
if(row.Orbit.results.forEach!=null)
```

or

```
 if(data.d.results.length > 0)
  {
    // Add your code

  }
```

or

```
if(row!=null)
```

doesnt work

EDIT: my full code is:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var tempArray = [];
    var chartObj = [['Orbit', 'Number']];

AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list')/items", function (data) {

    var countOrbit = {};
    var countSD = {}; 
    var countMT = {}; 
    var countIT = {}; 
    var countAI = {}; 


    data.d.results.forEach(function(row) {
        // each row
        row.Orbit.results.forEach(function(choiceOrbit) {
            // each choice of Orbit of single row
            if (countOrbit.hasOwnProperty(choiceOrbit)) {
                countOrbit[choiceOrbit] += 1;
            } else {
                countOrbit[choiceOrbit] = 1;
            }
        });
        row.SD.results.forEach(function(choiceSD) {
            // each choice of Orbit of single row
            if (countSD.hasOwnProperty(choiceSD)) {
                countSD[choiceSD] += 1;
            } else {
                countSD[choiceSD] = 1;
            }
        });
        row.MT.results.forEach(function(choiceMT) {
            // each choice of MT of single row
            if (countMT.hasOwnProperty(choiceMT)) {
                countMT[choiceMT] += 1;
            } else {
                countMT[choiceMT] = 1;
            }
        });
        row.IT.results.forEach(function(choiceIT) {
            // each choice of IT of single row
            if (countIT.hasOwnProperty(choiceIT)) {
                countIT[choiceIT] += 1;
            } else {
                countIT[choiceIT] = 1;
            }
        });
        row.AI.results.forEach(function(choiceAI) {
            // each choice of IT of single row
            if (countAI.hasOwnProperty(choiceAI)) {
                countAI[choiceAI] += 1;
            } else {
                countAI[choiceAI] = 1;
            }
        });
    });

    // Load Charts and the corechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawAllCharts(countOrbit, 'Orbit')});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawAllCharts(countSD, 'SD')});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawAllCharts(countMT, 'MT')});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawAllCharts(countIT, 'IT')});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawAllCharts(countAI, 'AI')});


    // Function for all Charts

    function drawAllCharts(countChoices, name) {
        var rows = [];
        for (var property in countChoices) {
            if (countChoices.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                rows.push([property, countChoices[property]]);
            }
        }


        var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        datatable.addColumn('string', 'Type');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
        datatable.addRows(rows);
        var options = {
            title: String(name),
            is3D: 'true'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(String(name)));
        chart.draw(datatable, options);
    }
    // End of function to draw charts


});
});
                function AjaxCall(url, success) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        },
                        success: success,
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                            alert('Something Went Wrong');
                        }
                    });
                }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <!--Table and divs that hold the pie charts-->
    <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td><div id="Orbit" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
        <td><div id="SD" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div id="MT" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
        <td><div id="IT" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
        <td><div id="AI" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a check with

```
if(row.Orbit!=null){
}
```

i think it will solve the issue as your Error Description itself suggested "Cannot read property 'results' of null" so when it got Error occurred row.Orbit was null.

Comment: this results in the same error. i think only one element is null not the whole

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the empty values out of Orbit column in the REST URL:

```
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Listname')/items?$top=5000&$Select=ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,Orbit,ID&$filter=(Orbit ne '')";
```

Updated: To filter multiple columns, refer below REST URL:

```
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmpData')/items?$top=5000&$Select=Country,EMPScore,Department,TechSkill,State,years,Result,ID&$filter=((Country eq 'USA')or(EMPScore eq '500')or(Department eq 'HR')or(TechSkill eq 'CRM')or(State eq 'LA'))and(years eq '27')and(Result eq '')"
```

Comment: thanks. can you explain me ab bit more what    &$filter=(Orbit ne '')     does? What is ne? Is there documentation?

Comment: $filter is used to filter the data of the list based on column names (in your case "Orbit" column) and ne means 'not equals'. [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#odata-query-operators-supported-in-the-sharepoint-rest-service](Reference MSDN)
Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!

Comment: ok and how can I get multiple columns were not only the Orbit column, which is not empty, is displayed

Comment: @FabianM I have added a REST URL to filter multiple columns. 
You can use ODate query operators in the filter based upon your conditions and requirement.

Comment: sorry, even with the filter i get: Internal Statistics.aspx:667 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null

Comment: i think the problem is with the forEach. If one element is empty it cannot read to property of it..

Comment: @FabianM According to my solution, if you filter out the empty columns from the REST URL itself, then you should not get empty data under "data.d.results". Try to log all the data in the console and check if it returns any record, also it would be helpful if you share your full code.

Comment: ok, i shared my full code.

Answer (score 0):

The user Mikel gave me the solution:

```
data.d.results.forEach(function(row) {
  // each row
  if (row.hasOwnProperty('Orbit') && row.Orbit != null) {
    row.Orbit.results.forEach(function(choiceOrbit) {
      // each choice of Orbit of single row
      if (countOrbit.hasOwnProperty(choiceOrbit)) {
          countOrbit[choiceOrbit] += 1;
      } else {
          countOrbit[choiceOrbit] = 1;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The solution was

```
 if (row.hasOwnProperty('Orbit') && row.Orbit != null) {
```